# MySQL IF in SELECT, replace the letter 'A' on 'AAA'

Tags: mysql, sql

How to display the list of employers, so that if the name is found the letter 'A' the system has replaced this name on 'AAA' ?
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Have you tried the `REPLACE` function?

Comment: No, i have tried:
SELECT STD_ID, 
     IF(STD_NAME = 'A', 'AAA', STD_NAME) AS STD_NAME
FROM STUDENT_TBL_;

Comment: That replaces the whole name if it's just `A`, it doesn't replace letters inside the name.

Answer (score 0):

As @shmosel said you can use the REPLACE function along with an UPDATE

```
UPDATE [yourtablename]
SET [yourfieldname] = REPLACE([yourfieldname], 'text to find', 'text to replace with')
WHERE [yourfieldname] LIKE '%text to find%'
```